# Pyomo Bonmin retrieve results early

Tags: python, pyomo

I'm using Pyomo with Bonmin on a fairly complicated model and it's using up 12+ hours to compute.

I've tried setting the parameter "bonmin.time_limit" to 1800 (30 mins) but it's not returning any variable values.

```
> ==========================================================
> = Solver Results                                         =
> ==========================================================
> ----------------------------------------------------------
>   Problem Information
> ----------------------------------------------------------
> Problem:
> - Lower bound: -inf
>   Upper bound: inf
>   Number of objectives: 1
>   Number of constraints: 0
>   Number of variables: 0
>   Sense: unknown
> ----------------------------------------------------------
>   Solver Information
> ----------------------------------------------------------
Solver:
> - Status: warning
>   Message: bonmin\x3a Optimization interupted on limit.
>   Termination condition: maxIterations
>   Id: 410
>   Error rc: 0
>   Time: 1813.3797194957733
> ----------------------------------------------------------
>   Solution Information
> ----------------------------------------------------------
Solution:
> - number of solutions: 0
>   number of solutions displayed: 0
```

It outputs multiple "blocks" of info.

Sometimes, it outputs:

```
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
 600 -2.7877808e+005 1.82e-012 6.71e-003 -11.0 2.75e+000 -10.5 1.00e+000 5.56e-001h  1
 601 -2.7877808e+005 1.82e-012 6.79e-010 -11.0 1.05e+000 -10.0 1.00e+000 1.00e+000f  1
Number of Iterations....: 601
                                   (scaled)                 (unscaled)
Objective...............: -7.4080060189689470e+002  -2.7877808250893821e+005
Dual infeasibility......:  6.7945537380025706e-010   2.5569264627135494e-007
Constraint violation....:  1.8189894035458565e-012   1.8189894035458565e-012
Complementarity.........:  8.6460028294267016e-011   3.2536637848060228e-008
Overall NLP error.......:  6.7945537380025706e-010   2.5569264627135494e-007

Number of objective function evaluations             = 1075
Number of objective gradient evaluations             = 516
Number of equality constraint evaluations            = 1075
Number of inequality constraint evaluations          = 1075
Number of equality constraint Jacobian evaluations   = 604
Number of inequality constraint Jacobian evaluations = 604
Number of Lagrangian Hessian evaluations             = 601
Total CPU secs in IPOPT (w/o function evaluations)   =    101.103
Total CPU secs in NLP function evaluations           =      0.694

EXIT: Optimal Solution Found.
```

But then, it immediately runs another set of calculations (this continues from the previous block):

```
 (Previous block) EXIT: Optimal Solution Found.
This is Ipopt version 3.10.1, running with linear solver mumps.

Number of nonzeros in equality constraint Jacobian...:     6670
Number of nonzeros in inequality constraint Jacobian.:    13580
Number of nonzeros in Lagrangian Hessian.............:      196

Total number of variables............................:     3694
                     variables with only lower bounds:     2730
                variables with lower and upper bounds:      964
                     variables with only upper bounds:        0
Total number of equality constraints.................:     1238
Total number of inequality constraints...............:     3612
        inequality constraints with only lower bounds:      160
   inequality constraints with lower and upper bounds:        0
        inequality constraints with only upper bounds:     3452

iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
   0 -2.7146106e+005 9.00e+000 1.66e+000   0.0 0.00e+000    -  0.00e+000 0.00e+000   0
   1 -2.7135545e+005 9.00e+000 3.38e+000   4.8 3.59e+006    -  8.46e-008 2.71e-007f  1
   2 -2.7112865e+005 9.00e+000 7.89e+000   4.7 3.14e+006    -  2.80e-007 6.37e-007f  1
   3 -2.7083702e+005 9.00e+000 8.43e+000   4.2 8.99e+005    -  2.67e-006 2.79e-006f  1
```

And so on...

Is there any way to get the solutions from the first block?

It just repeats like this forever.

Comment: Ignoring the problem information part (looks bad; wrongly parsed?): maybe bonmin did not find a feasible solution? Maybe remove some constraints to check if easier problems are working with early-stopping (yes: that might be non-trivial in some problems as unboundedness can be a problem). And: is your problem convex?

Comment: You can also use tee=True or --stream-solver to get the solver output information while Bonmin is running.

Comment: I'll paste the outputs in a new answer to make it easier to look at

Answer (score 0):

It outputs multiple "blocks" of info.

Sometimes, it outputs:

```
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
 600 -2.7877808e+005 1.82e-012 6.71e-003 -11.0 2.75e+000 -10.5 1.00e+000 5.56e-001h  1
 601 -2.7877808e+005 1.82e-012 6.79e-010 -11.0 1.05e+000 -10.0 1.00e+000 1.00e+000f  1
Number of Iterations....: 601
                                   (scaled)                 (unscaled)
Objective...............: -7.4080060189689470e+002  -2.7877808250893821e+005
Dual infeasibility......:  6.7945537380025706e-010   2.5569264627135494e-007
Constraint violation....:  1.8189894035458565e-012   1.8189894035458565e-012
Complementarity.........:  8.6460028294267016e-011   3.2536637848060228e-008
Overall NLP error.......:  6.7945537380025706e-010   2.5569264627135494e-007

Number of objective function evaluations             = 1075
Number of objective gradient evaluations             = 516
Number of equality constraint evaluations            = 1075
Number of inequality constraint evaluations          = 1075
Number of equality constraint Jacobian evaluations   = 604
Number of inequality constraint Jacobian evaluations = 604
Number of Lagrangian Hessian evaluations             = 601
Total CPU secs in IPOPT (w/o function evaluations)   =    101.103
Total CPU secs in NLP function evaluations           =      0.694

EXIT: Optimal Solution Found.
```

But then, it immediately runs another set of calculations (this continues from the previous block):

```
 (Previous block) EXIT: Optimal Solution Found.
This is Ipopt version 3.10.1, running with linear solver mumps.

Number of nonzeros in equality constraint Jacobian...:     6670
Number of nonzeros in inequality constraint Jacobian.:    13580
Number of nonzeros in Lagrangian Hessian.............:      196

Total number of variables............................:     3694
                     variables with only lower bounds:     2730
                variables with lower and upper bounds:      964
                     variables with only upper bounds:        0
Total number of equality constraints.................:     1238
Total number of inequality constraints...............:     3612
        inequality constraints with only lower bounds:      160
   inequality constraints with lower and upper bounds:        0
        inequality constraints with only upper bounds:     3452

iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
   0 -2.7146106e+005 9.00e+000 1.66e+000   0.0 0.00e+000    -  0.00e+000 0.00e+000   0
   1 -2.7135545e+005 9.00e+000 3.38e+000   4.8 3.59e+006    -  8.46e-008 2.71e-007f  1
   2 -2.7112865e+005 9.00e+000 7.89e+000   4.7 3.14e+006    -  2.80e-007 6.37e-007f  1
   3 -2.7083702e+005 9.00e+000 8.43e+000   4.2 8.99e+005    -  2.67e-006 2.79e-006f  1
```

And so on...

Is there any way to get the solutions from the first block?

It just repeats like this forever.

Comment: In the future, please update your original question with additional information and do not post additional information as an "answer".  Those blocks of output are from the NLP subproblem solves (in this case, `ipopt`), and do not correspond to actual incumbent (integer-feasible) solutions to the MINLP.  As a result, bonmin does not report those solutions.

Comment: I see. Are there any parameters that would enable me to get a rough approximate of the answers quickly?

Comment: You can look through the bonmin options: https://www.coin-or.org/Bonmin/option_pages/options_list_bonmin.html. I don't know of anything in Pyomo that would be able to give you what you want.

Comment: I have a preliminary MINLP solver implementation that might be able to do what you want to, though it hasn't been merged in. https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/pull/166